# How to Create Login and session management for android using Security and Session Spring and RestTemplate

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, authentication

I want create an android application that have login layout and when user login to the app, authentication and session managed by Spring Security and Redis. I want to use Rest Template for message passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this, I found a good solution. 
We must create a maven project like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

then add following line to application.properties file.

```
spring.redis.host=192.168.174.135
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.session.store-type=redis
```

now we must run redis server on port 6379. for more info refer to [this](https://redis.io/).
Now, create three class on server side like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private String tokenKey = "some token goes here";
@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
@Autowired private CustomTokenBasedRememberMeService tokenBasedRememberMeService;
@Autowired private RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeService).and().exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());;
    auth.authenticationProvider(rememberMeAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
@Override public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
@Bean public CustomTokenBasedRememberMeService tokenBasedRememberMeService(){
    CustomTokenBasedRememberMeService service = new CustomTokenBasedRememberMeService(tokenKey, userDetailsServiceImpl);
    service.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    service.setCookieName("at");
    return service;
}
@Bean
RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider(){
    return new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider(tokenKey);
}
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
{

private static List<UserObject> users = new ArrayList();

public UserDetailsServiceImpl() {
    //in a real application, instead of using local data,
    // we will find user details by some other means e.g. from an external system
    users.add(new UserObject("ali", "123", "USER"));
    users.add(new UserObject("reza", "234", "USER"));
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<UserObject> user = users.stream()
            .filter(u -> u.name.equals(username))
            .findAny();
    if (!user.isPresent()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found by name: " + username);
    }
    return toUserDetails(user.get());
}

private UserDetails toUserDetails(UserObject userObject) {
    return User.withUsername(userObject.name)
            .password(userObject.password)
            .roles(userObject.role).build();
}

private static class UserObject {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String role;

    public UserObject(String name, String password, String role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
}
```

```
@RestController
public class Gateway
{

@RequestMapping(value = {"/error"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String error() {

    return "Error";
}
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = "application/json")
public Message homePage() {
    Message message = new Message(1 , "test" , "this is a test");
    return message;
}
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/test"}, method = RequestMethod.GET )
public Message test() {
    //Message message = new Message(1 , "test" , "this is a test");
    CustomMessage customMessage = new CustomMessage();
    customMessage.setS1("tests1");
    customMessage.setS2("test s2");
    customMessage.setSubject("test");
    return customMessage;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                              @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

    if (error != null) {
        return "login?error";
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        return "login?logout";
    }
    return "ok";
}
}
```

Now in android client we must define a login layout and two class like this:

```
public class Login extends Activity
{
Button btnSubmit = null;
EditText edUsername = null;
EditText edPassword = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    edUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    edPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConnectToLogin connectToLogin = new ConnectToLogin();
            String url = getString(R.string.base_uri) + "/login";
            String username = edUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = edPassword.getText().toString();
            connectToLogin.execute(username , password , url);
        }
    });
}
public void doResult(Boolean sw)
{
    if(sw == true)
    {
        MessagePassing<Message> messagePassing = new MessagePassing<>();
        String url = getString(R.string.base_uri) + "/api/home";
        messagePassing.GetFrom(url);
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result","OK");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this , "Authentication failed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class ConnectToLogin extends AsyncTask<String , Void , Boolean>
{
    public  int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
    public  int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            // param[0] = username
            // param[1] = password
            // param[2] = URL
            String username = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            URL url = new URL(params[2]);
            java.net.CookieManager cookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("username", username)
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", password);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();
            int result = conn.getResponseCode();
            if ( result == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    input.append(line);
                }
                String strInput = input.toString();
                if(strInput.equals("ok"))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String a = e.getCause().toString();
            return false;
        }
        return  false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        System.out.println("Login was =" + result);
        doResult(result);
    }
}
}
```

```
public class MessagePassing<T>
{
public void GetFrom(String url)
{
    new Connection().execute(url);
}
private class Connection extends AsyncTask<String , Void , T>
{
    @Override
    protected T doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String strurl = params[0];
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        T result = null;
        try {
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
            ResponseEntity rssResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
                    strurl,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    requestEntity,
                    Message.class);
            result = (T) rssResponse.getBody();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return result;

}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(T result) {
        MessageListener<T> messageMessageListener = new MessageListener<>();
        messageMessageListener.OnDataReceived(result);
    }
}
}
```